# Two names on US tax refund, filed as 'single'

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, check, refund

I received my US federal tax return earlier this month. When I first looked at the check, I noticed it had a % symbol, followed by my mother's name on the line below the one with my name. 
It looks like:

MY NAME
% MOTHER'S NAME
111 EXAMPLE ROAD
AUSTIN TX 99999 9999

I thought this was odd, so I called my mother that evening, and she agreed that It was strange. I didn't think much of it until I tried to cash the check at Walmart, and they said I needed her present to do so.

Quick facts:

- We both have the same mailing address
- I filed as 'single' (I know this for a fact)
- I received, and cashed without incident, my federal return last year (I do not recall if my mother's name was on the check).
- My mother has not filed her federal taxes this year.
- She claims (though I have no 1st hand materials by which to verify) that she did not claim me as a dependent last year.

My questions are as follows:

- What can I do to get this check cashed?

Walmart wants her there in person with photo ID. We do not get along and only speak on occasion however, so this seems unlikely. I am going to take it to a bank tomorrow to open an account with and see if they take it.

- Why?

I don't expect any IRS employees on this forum, but any info on what this means, how this happened, and/or how to prevent it would be  greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just to clarify, it appears that what you got is a tax REFUND.  The tax return is the form(s) you send in - F1040 and so on.

Comment: How does your mom pay for her living expenses if she didn't have any income? I have a guess here, but please provide some more info...

Comment: BTW: the bank won't take it without your mom present.

Comment: @BenMiller: Yes. On typewriters, the % key was, in fact, often used as a "ligature" for c/o and I presume that's the intent here.

Comment: Had the same thing happen with my son. He dose not have a bank account and therefore went to Walmart. They made my husband come in even though I told them the % sign only meant "in care of."

Comment: Ben Miller is correct! Your mother's name it's just part of the address.

Answer (score 17):

The percent sign stands for "C/O", which means "Care Of." Care Of is just a part of a mailing address when you are addressing a letter to someone at someone else's house. With windowed envelopes, the entire mailing address is printed on the face of the check.

This is not a 2 party check; your mother's name is a part of your address. Try a real bank instead of Walmart, and see what they say. You should be able to cash it without your mother's cooperation.

Answer (score 0):

My son received his check today and between his name and his father's name is a "%" symbol. I called our credit union today and they said our son only need be present to cash and/or deposit it. We did claim our son as a dependent so I'm figuring that is why that symbol is there. That or because my husband filled out the forms and filed them.

Comment: Probably the latter.