# Must a c/o party be present in order for payee to cash a check?

Tags: check, endorsement

I did taxes for friend 90 miles away and she authorized state to talk with me regarding tax prep since I understand filings. Refund check is made payable to her c/o me. She does not have a bank and cashes checks at major retail center. They say I must be present in order for her to cash her check. My endorsement alone is not sufficient but I must be present. I say c/o is merely part of address and there is only one payee so only she must endorse the check and be present. Your thoughts?

Comment: Whose mailing address is on the check, yours or your friend’s?

Comment: Related: [Two names on US tax refund, filed as single](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/44859/10997)

Comment: State tax refund mailed to friend's address. I do not think friend's address is on check but I am positive my address is not on the check. Friend checked box on tax form and provided my name and phone number to authorize me to answer questions about the return.

Comment: I just confirmed that friend's address is on the check.

Comment: Thank you Ben Miller. I read your reply to similar question and it clearly applies. I appreciate your input very much.

Answer (score 4):

I’m sure you are correct, and if she were dealing with a bank, I don’t think she would have any problem with it.

The check cashing service she is dealing with may have different rules, or it may just be a misunderstanding of the teller she talked to. She should try talking to a manager there.

My final thought: go see your friend.

Comment: I just realized the question @BenMiller linked is a duplicate and has more detailed answers than this.

Comment: Thank you. I am not certain how to mark my question as answered but I consider it so. The retailer is Walmart (I named because I see they are named in another query.) I did talk to a manager and they are pretty ignorant. I will visit tomorrow and play the game. I appreciate your input very much.