# If a check is made payable to my son c/o me but mailed to my son, can he deposit it into his own account without my endorsement?

Tags: endorsement

Not sure why but my son received a refund at his house that is payble to him c/o me.  Can he deposit without my endorsement?  I am not on his account.

Comment: closely related: https://money.stackexchange.com/q/91845/5458

Answer (score 5):

Yes, your son can deposit or cash the check. c/o is merely a direction to the mailman as to where to deliver the envelope and doesn’t give you any rights to the money.

Comment: Exactly. It’s “and” which creates an issue needing two signatures.